# Which is Opera Next's directory?

Tags: software-center, synaptic, opera, tar

I recently installed Opera Next **via tar**.

I saw it, "played" with it, and now I want to uninstall it.

Where can I find it's directory? The package is neither in Ubuntu Software Center, nor in Synaptic Package Manager.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
~/.local/bin/uninstall-opera-next
```

or if you installed it globally:

```
sudo /usr/local/bin/uninstall-opera-next
```

After that you'd need to manually remove the user date in *~/.opera-next*.